# How do I install and preauthorize app so I can use the JWT Bearer token flow?

Tags: oauth2, jwt

I'm trying to follow the instructions in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5 and get an invalid request with an error description of "refresh_token scope is required and the connected app should be installed and preauthorized."

In the documentation it says I should "Install and preauthorize the app" - but I have no idea how to go about this, and I can't find the appropriate docs. I've looked around several config screens for the app and can't see anything obvious. As a salesforce novice I'm stuck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are much more detailed instructions on setting up JWT authentication in the [Salesforce DX Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm#sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow), because JWT is often used for CI and other headless authentication use cases. While the documentation is somewhat SFDX-specific, it covers establishing a JWT flow well.

The first couple of steps you'll need to do are

- [Create a Private Key and Self-Signed Digital Certificate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_key_and_cert.htm)
- [Create a Connected App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_connected_app.htm)

Your digital certificate gets uploaded on the app, and the critical "preauthorize" step takes place at the Connected App level as well:

> In the OAuth Policies section, select Admin approved users are pre-authorized for Permitted Users, and click OK.
>
> Click Manage Profiles and then click Manage Permission Sets. Select the profiles and permission sets that are pre-authorized to use this connected app. Create permission sets if necessary.

This allows JWT authentication requests to complete (for users on the relevant Profiles and Permission Sets) with no UI-based authorization at all.

Comment: I have followed all those steps (only difference is I don't have any permission sets - are they required or can you use profiles only?)

Comment: You can use profiles only, so long as you pre-authorize them. What scopes do you have selected?

Comment: Aha - the app was missing the "Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)" OAuth scope, after reading the instructions for Create a Connected App the error message suddenly makes a lot of sense!